# Emacs change font of a single word (or sentence), not of the whole buffer

Tags: emacs, fonts

Somehow I don't find a way of changing the font size of a specific string of text.

I know how to do it globally or temporarily for the whole buffer.Changing the default font is not the issue here.

Sometimes I use math symbols like ω, Ω or ב and want to change these to a bigger font. I'd need a simple way of doing this. Alternatives to make these symbols more visible are welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is an Emacs **face** that uses larger size characters. See the face attribute `:height`, for instance, in the Elisp manual, node `Face Attributes`.

You can apply a face to any piece of text (e.g., a word or expression).  You can do this by program or manually.  If by program, it can be done using `font-lock-keywords` (automatic syntax highlighting) or using any of various text highlighting functions.

Such highlighting can be effected using the `face` text property or the `face` overlay property; that is,  it can be attached to buffer text (or to a string), on the one hand, or overlaid on top of the buffer, on the other hand.

See also:

- [EmacsWiki - Faces category](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryFaces)
- [EmacsWiki - Font-Lock](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontLockMode)
- [EmacsWiki - Highlighting](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightTemporarily)
- Emacs manual, node `Enriched Text`